# Is there a word for describing "smoothness" quantitatively?

Tags: analysis

I've long wondered how to "quantitatively" describe how smooth a function is.

For instance, a 1000 term Fourier series for a the Heaviside step function is technically smooth, as it has infinite derivatives.  But, when compared to the first term, it is much "spikier".

I often want to find myself saying the 1000-term Fourier series is "less smooth" than the single term... but is there a good word for that?

Comment: This may be of some interest, at least regarding your example of Fourier series: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Answer (score 1):

One measure of "spikiness" (or maybe "wobblyness" would be more fitting) is the [total variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation). The formal definition is that $$
  TV_a^b(f) = \sup_{a = x_1<x_2<\ldots x_n=b} \sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)\right| \text{,}
$$
meaning that you look at arbitrary fine partitions $[a,b] = [x_0,x_1] \cup [x_1,x_2] \cup \ldots \cup [x_{n-1},x_n]$ and sum up the amount by which $f$ *varies* between the start and the end of each subinterval.

If $f'$ exists and is riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$, then $$
  TV_a^b(f) = \int_a^b |f'(x)| \,dx \text{,}
$$
and it follows that for such $f$ you have that $$
  TV_a^b(f) \leq (b-a)\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)| \text{,}
$$
meaning that the smaller a function's derivative is in $[a,b]$, the less "wobbly" that function is.

The dependency on the interval length is a bit unfortunate in that last inequality, but there's an easy remedy - just normalize with the interval length. So let's define the normalized wobblyness of $f$ on $[a,b]$ $$
  W_a^b(f) = \frac{1}{b-a}TV_a^b(f) = \sup_{a = x_1<x_2<\ldots x_n=b} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\left|f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n)\right|}{b-a} \text{,}
$$
then $$
  W_a^b(f) \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)|
$$
if $f'$ exists and is riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Related with the comment of Andrew D., you can be interested in read about the [Runge phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon#Mitigations_to_the_problem), in the section of constrained minimization. Maybe what you want is to limit the (absolute value of the) derivatives to be constrained in certain interval.